# Jquery Sliding panel plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've been looking for a jquery plugin for the last couple hours.
What I'm looking for is a panel that stays on screen all the time off to the side of my full story pages. 
Similar to the follow me sharing tabs on mashable.com and for a similar purpose. I simply want the tweet digg this and share on facebook buttons on my page to stay on screen no matter where on the page the user is currently reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're after but try [jQuery Scroll Follow](http://kitchen.net-perspective.com/open-source/scroll-follow/)

Comment: actually the first example they show should do what i need thanks alot for the help still open to more if you know any

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do would be best done using css position:fixed applied to whatever drawer element you have. Position:Fixed; in css defines a position for an element based on the browser window regardless of the page content position, so that when you scroll, the "fixed" positioned element stays still.

[W3C's page on this property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_position.asp)

Comment: not exactly what i want looking for the animation effects that jquery gives you